# Can't insert data into mysql database using php from another form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am newbie in php and trying to build a forum site using Nattive PHP,  I cannot enter data into the database, in that case the database is connected properly. I keep stuck during insert a data using reply.php to add as a reply from the topic
I'm sorry for uploading a lot of pictures
database
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMHE9.jpg)

1[topic.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ayQN.jpg)
2[topic.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vxMm.jpg)

reply.php <<= **the problem is here**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'interface.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    echo 'can't dirrectly call this one.';
}
else
{
    if(!$_SESSION['signed_in'])
    {
        echo 'login first.';
    }

    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts(post_content, post_date, post_topic, post_by)
                VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['reply-content']) . "', NOW(), " . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']) . ", " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'comment fail, try again!'; //**this is what i got every time call this one**
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'comment succesfully <a href="topic.php?id=' . htmlentities($_GET['id']) . '">the topic</a>.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you used here single and dual quotes both `VALUES (' "`

Comment: @MUFAzmi That bit is fine. The double quotes enclose the string and the single quotes are part of it

Comment: This line: `echo 'can't dirrectly call this one.';`. You can't just place single quotes in a string that is enclosed in single quotes. Either escape it (`echo 'can\'t dirrectly call this one.';`), or use double quotes (`echo "can't dirrectly call this one.";`)